# Django OpenStack Horizon - Admin templates are not rendering properly

Tags: python, django, openstack, openstack-horizon, horizon

Upon creating my own panel in OpenStack Horizon I am unable to properly view the admin panels (Overview panel: Pie Charts not appearing, Instances: Unable to generate Instance but can view possible instances to choose from). This occurs when my new panel is 'enabled' within the enabled folder. The panel that Ive added is not Horizon-centric, and the 'magic' of Horizon is not taken advantage of (I find its syntax odd). Any idea as to why the admin panels are no longer rendered properly? It seems to be a template issue but I have no idea how to fix it.

settings.py code:

```
# Standard Library
import logging
import os
import sys
import warnings
from collections import OrderedDict

# Django Library
import django
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

# OpenStack Library
from openstack_dashboard import exceptions
from openstack_dashboard.static_settings import find_static_files
from openstack_dashboard.static_settings import get_staticfiles_dirs


warnings.formatwarning = lambda message, category, *args, **kwargs: \
    '%s: %s' % (category.__name__, message)

ROOT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
BIN_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, '..', 'bin'))
BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

if ROOT_PATH not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(ROOT_PATH)

DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

SITE_BRANDING = 'Rockwell Automation'

WEBROOT = '/'
LOGIN_URL = None
LOGOUT_URL = None
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = None
STATIC_ROOT = None
STATIC_URL = None

ROOT_URLCONF = 'openstack_dashboard.urls'

HORIZON_CONFIG = {
    'user_home': 'openstack_dashboard.views.get_user_home',
    'ajax_queue_limit': 10,
    'auto_fade_alerts': {
        'delay': 3000,
        'fade_duration': 1500,
        'types': ['alert-success', 'alert-info']
    },
    'bug_url': None,
    'help_url': "http://docs.openstack.org",
    'exceptions': {'recoverable': exceptions.RECOVERABLE,
                   'not_found': exceptions.NOT_FOUND,
                   'unauthorized': exceptions.UNAUTHORIZED},
    'modal_backdrop': 'static',
    'angular_modules': [],
    'js_files': [],
    'js_spec_files': [],
    'external_templates': [],
    'plugins': []
}

# Set to True to allow users to upload images to glance via Horizon server.
# When enabled, a file form field will appear on the create image form.
# See documentation for deployment considerations.
HORIZON_IMAGES_ALLOW_UPLOAD = True

# The OPENSTACK_IMAGE_BACKEND settings can be used to customize features
# in the OpenStack Dashboard related to the Image service, such as the list
# of supported image formats.
OPENSTACK_IMAGE_BACKEND = {
    'image_formats': [
        ('', _('Select format')),
        ('aki', _('AKI - Amazon Kernel Image')),
        ('ami', _('AMI - Amazon Machine Image')),
        ('ari', _('ARI - Amazon Ramdisk Image')),
        ('docker', _('Docker')),
        ('iso', _('ISO - Optical Disk Image')),
        ('ova', _('OVA - Open Virtual Appliance')),
        ('qcow2', _('QCOW2 - QEMU Emulator')),
        ('raw', _('Raw')),
        ('vdi', _('VDI - Virtual Disk Image')),
        ('vhd', _('VHD - Virtual Hard Disk')),
        ('vmdk', _('VMDK - Virtual Machine Disk')),
    ]
}

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)
if django.VERSION >= (1, 8, 0):
    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES += (
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',)
else:
    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES += ('django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware',)
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES += (
    'horizon.middleware.HorizonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'horizon.context_processors.horizon',
    'openstack_dashboard.context_processors.openstack',
)

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    ('django.template.loaders.cached.Loader', (
        'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
        'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
        'horizon.loaders.TemplateLoader',
    )),
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'templates').replace('\\','/'),
    os.path.join(ROOT_PATH,'dashboards\\stex\\panel1\\templates').replace('\\','/'),
    os.path.join(ROOT_PATH,'dashboards\\stex\\panel2\\templates').replace('\\','/'),
    os.path.join(ROOT_PATH,'dashboards\\stex\\panel3\\templates').replace('\\','/'),
    os.path.join(ROOT_PATH,'dashboards\\stex\\panel4\\templates').replace('\\','/'),
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)

COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/scss', 'horizon.utils.scss_filter.HorizonScssFilter'),
)

COMPRESS_CSS_FILTERS = (
    'compressor.filters.css_default.CssAbsoluteFilter',
)

COMPRESS_ENABLED = True
COMPRESS_OUTPUT_DIR = 'dashboard'
COMPRESS_CSS_HASHING_METHOD = 'hash'
COMPRESS_PARSER = 'compressor.parser.HtmlParser'

INSTALLED_APPS = [
   'openstack_dashboard',
    #'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'django_pyscss',
    'openstack_dashboard.django_pyscss_fix',
    'compressor',
    'horizon',
    'openstack_auth',

]

TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('openstack_auth.backend.KeystoneBackend',)
AUTHENTICATION_URLS = ['openstack_auth.urls']
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'openstack_auth.User'
MESSAGE_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage'

SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies'
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False

# SESSION_TIMEOUT is a method to supersede the token timeout with a shorter
# horizon session timeout (in seconds).  So if your token expires in 60
# minutes, a value of 1800 will log users out after 30 minutes
SESSION_TIMEOUT = 3600

# When using cookie-based sessions, log error when the session cookie exceeds
# the following size (common browsers drop cookies above a certain size):
SESSION_COOKIE_MAX_SIZE = 4093

# when doing upgrades, it may be wise to stick to PickleSerializer
# NOTE(berendt): Check during the K-cycle if this variable can be removed.
#                https://bugs.launchpad.net/horizon/+bug/1349463
SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'

LANGUAGES = (
    ('cs', 'Czech'),
    ('de', 'German'),
    ('en', 'English'),
    ('en-au', 'Australian English'),
    ('en-gb', 'British English'),
    ('es', 'Spanish'),
    ('fr', 'French'),
    ('it', 'Italian'),
    ('ja', 'Japanese'),
    ('ko', 'Korean (Korea)'),
    ('pl', 'Polish'),
    ('pt-br', 'Portuguese (Brazil)'),
    ('ru', 'Russian'),
    ('tr', 'Turkish'),
    ('zh-cn', 'Simplified Chinese'),
    ('zh-tw', 'Chinese (Taiwan)'),
)
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME = 'horizon_language'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

OPENSTACK_KEYSTONE_DEFAULT_ROLE = '_member_'

DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER_FILTER = 'horizon.exceptions.HorizonReporterFilter'

POLICY_FILES_PATH = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, "conf")
# Map of local copy of service policy files
POLICY_FILES = {
    'identity': 'keystone_policy.json',
    'compute': 'nova_policy.json',
    'volume': 'cinder_policy.json',
    'image': 'glance_policy.json',
    'orchestration': 'heat_policy.json',
    'network': 'neutron_policy.json',
    'telemetry': 'ceilometer_policy.json',
}

SECRET_KEY = None
LOCAL_PATH = None

SECURITY_GROUP_RULES = {
    'all_tcp': {
        'name': _('All TCP'),
        'ip_protocol': 'tcp',
        'from_port': '1',
        'to_port': '65535',
    },
    'all_udp': {
        'name': _('All UDP'),
        'ip_protocol': 'udp',
        'from_port': '1',
        'to_port': '65535',
    },
    'all_icmp': {
        'name': _('All ICMP'),
        'ip_protocol': 'icmp',
        'from_port': '-1',
        'to_port': '-1',
    },
}

ADD_INSTALLED_APPS = []

# directory for custom theme, set as default.
# It can be overridden in local_settings.py
DEFAULT_THEME_PATH = 'themes/default'
CUSTOM_THEME_PATH = DEFAULT_THEME_PATH

try:
    from local.local_settings import *  # noqa
except ImportError:
    logging.warning("No local_settings file found.")

if not WEBROOT.endswith('/'):
    WEBROOT += '/'
if LOGIN_URL is None:
    LOGIN_URL = WEBROOT + 'auth/login/'
if LOGOUT_URL is None:
    LOGOUT_URL = WEBROOT + 'auth/logout/'
if LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL is None:
    LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = WEBROOT

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, '..', 'media'))
MEDIA_URL = WEBROOT + 'media/'

if STATIC_ROOT is None:
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, '..', 'static'))

if STATIC_URL is None:
    STATIC_URL = WEBROOT + 'static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = get_staticfiles_dirs(STATIC_URL)

CUSTOM_THEME = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, CUSTOM_THEME_PATH)

# If a custom template directory exists within our custom theme, then prepend
# it to our first-come, first-serve TEMPLATE_DIRS
if os.path.exists(os.path.join(CUSTOM_THEME, 'templates')):
    TEMPLATE_DIRS = \
        (os.path.join(CUSTOM_THEME, 'templates'),) + TEMPLATE_DIRS

# Only expose the subdirectory 'static' if it exists from a custom theme,
# allowing other logic to live with a theme that we might not want to expose
# statically
if os.path.exists(os.path.join(CUSTOM_THEME, 'static')):
    CUSTOM_THEME = os.path.join(CUSTOM_THEME, 'static')

# Only collect and expose the default theme if the user chose to set a
# different theme
if DEFAULT_THEME_PATH != CUSTOM_THEME_PATH:
    STATICFILES_DIRS.append(
        ('themes/default', os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, DEFAULT_THEME_PATH)),
    )

STATICFILES_DIRS.append(
    ('custom', CUSTOM_THEME),
)

# Load the subdirectory 'img' of a custom theme if it exists, thereby allowing
# very granular theme overrides of all dashboard img files using the first-come
# first-serve filesystem loader.
if os.path.exists(os.path.join(CUSTOM_THEME, 'img')):
    STATICFILES_DIRS.insert(0, ('dashboard/img',
                            os.path.join(CUSTOM_THEME, 'img')))

# populate HORIZON_CONFIG with auto-discovered JavaScript sources, mock files,
# specs files and external templates.
find_static_files(HORIZON_CONFIG)

# Ensure that we always have a SECRET_KEY set, even when no local_settings.py
# file is present. See local_settings.py.example for full documentation on the
# horizon.utils.secret_key module and its use.
if not SECRET_KEY:
    if not LOCAL_PATH:
        LOCAL_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),
                                  'local')

    from horizon.utils import secret_key
    SECRET_KEY = secret_key.generate_or_read_from_file(os.path.join(LOCAL_PATH,
                                                       '.secret_key_store'))

# Load the pluggable dashboard settings
import openstack_dashboard.enabled
import openstack_dashboard.local.enabled
from openstack_dashboard.utils import settings

INSTALLED_APPS = list(INSTALLED_APPS)  # Make sure it's mutable
settings.update_dashboards(
    [
        openstack_dashboard.enabled,
        openstack_dashboard.local.enabled,
    ],
    HORIZON_CONFIG,
    INSTALLED_APPS,
)
INSTALLED_APPS[0:0] = ADD_INSTALLED_APPS

from openstack_auth import policy
POLICY_CHECK_FUNCTION = policy.check

# Add HORIZON_CONFIG to the context information for offline compression
COMPRESS_OFFLINE_CONTEXT = {
    'WEBROOT': WEBROOT,
    'STATIC_URL': STATIC_URL,
    'HORIZON_CONFIG': HORIZON_CONFIG,
}

if DEBUG:
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

# during django reloads and an active user is logged in, the monkey
# patch below will not otherwise be applied in time - resulting in developers
# appearing to be logged out.  In typical production deployments this section
# below may be omitted, though it should not be harmful
from openstack_auth import utils as auth_utils
auth_utils.patch_middleware_get_user()

CSRF_COOKIE_AGE = None

# Dictionary used for the panels
fw_tested = OrderedDict()
# fw_test key = revision of firmware
# Value example options for query: '1756-L85S', '1756-L8zS, '1756-L8z', '1756-L7xS
# Maintain lowest firmware revision in panel1 and the highest in panel4
fw_tested['28'] = ["1756-L85", "5069-L3", "1756-L7x", "1756-L71", "1756-L7xS", "1769-L18"] #panel1
fw_tested['29'] = ["1756-L85", "5069-L3", "1756-L7x", "1756-L7xS", "1769-L18"] #panel2
fw_tested['30'] = ["1756-L85", "5069-L3", "1756-L7x", "1756-L7xS", "1769-L18"] #panel3
fw_tested['31'] = ["1756-L85", "5069-L3", "1756-L7x", "1756-L7xS", "1769-L18"] #panel4
```

Within settings.py I am pointing to the newly created templates, this however is not needed if Horizons syntax is utilized (So I believe). Ive also got static files (css) rendering the new panel, not sure that this matters. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had stored static variables in settings.py to access in a custom dashboard. As a result the Horizon dashboards were broken. The static variables should be store elsewhere.